# How to configure $LOAD_PATH in VS Code's debugger for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to use VS Code's debugger. It works fine for local files, but not RSpecs.

for example, i have the `part_1.rb` under `lib/` and `part_1_spec.rb` under `spec/`.

`part_1_spec.rb` is like

```rb
require "part_1"

describe "Part 1:" do
```

It works fine if I use `byebug` as debugger and run the spec as `bundle exec rspec part_1_spec.rb`, but when I use VS code debugger, I have to do `require_relative "../lib/part_1"` and `require "Rspec" include "Rspec"` otherwise it will unable to load properly.

Is there any way I can configure $LOAD_PATH in VSCode so that I don't have to change these spec files? And I will have many projects so I don't want to do it for each project.

The following is my current launch.json for my VS code debugger

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "RSpec - active spec file only",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "args": [
                "-I",
                "${workspaceRoot}/lib",
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Local File",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I for `program` I should specify the new version of my installed Rspec and that would automatically look for files under the root folder

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "RSpec - active spec file only",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/usr/local/bin/rspec",
            "args": ["${file}"],
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Local File",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd":"${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
    ]
}
```